# How to get the query and make another one based on the same var?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Thank in advance for your help, I am using [Search and Filter Pro](http://www.designsandcode.com/wordpress-plugins/search-filter-pro/) and [Relevanssi Premium](https://www.relevanssi.com/buy-premium/), I need your help to display one post type above another one.

So I Have two CPT:

- School
- Premium Schools

I want the "premium school" to be in the first places of the results and then the normal schools.

And here is the original `results.php` of Search & Filter Pro:

```
 <?php if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    ?>

    Found <?php echo $query->found_posts; ?> Results<br />
    Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?><br />

    <div class="pagination">

        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
        <?php
            /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
            {
                echo "<br />";
                wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php
    while ($query->have_posts())
    {
        $query->the_post();

        ?>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p><br /><?php the_excerpt(); ?><p>
            <?php 
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    echo '<p>';
                    the_post_thumbnail("small");
                    echo '</p>';
                }
            ?>
            <p><?php the_category(); ?><p>
            <p><?php the_tags(); ?><p>
            <p><small><?php the_date(); ?></small><p>

        </div>

        <hr />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    Page <?php echo $query->query['paged']; ?> of <?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?><br />

    <div class="pagination">

        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
        <?php
            /* example code for using the wp_pagenavi plugin */
            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
            {
                echo "<br />";
                wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
else
{
    echo "No Results Found";
}
?>
```

Now I want to add a Post type using the same `$Query` and place it on top of the results..

I have tried using `get_post_type` but It only searches the first page of the results and not all the pages so it's not really what I want. I want it to look for *ALL* -Premium schools- and then *ALL* normal schools.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a count when you say: *"Now I want to add a Post type using the same $Query and place it on top of the results"*?

Comment: I am looking to do two queries one on top of the another where it takes the same data entered on "search and filter pro" (post type depending on the taxonomy etc) and place it on top of the page.. 

For example : Someone looking for a school in finance in los angeles 

So it will bring the premium school first, and then the normal school where u can see the query working just fine above.

Comment: So right now it mixes them in with each other? You want to sort them first so the user has to go through the first batch of premium schools before they start going through standard schools, correct?

Comment: Do you have control over the `$query`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted to do, btw I am a newby on PHP :p , I can put some functions on $query, but I don't know what you mean by having control over the $query..

Comment: Here is the documentation of the plugin I am using : http://www.designsandcode.com/documentation/search-filter-pro/getting-started/ I asked a question in the support of the designandcode but no one answered me yet

Comment: If you can manipulate the `$query` whereby you can access the sql statement, you can sort via sql. So if the query sends something like "select * from `wp_posts` where `whatever`='whatever', LIMIT 10" you can add an `order by` in there so it sorts them.

Comment: On the documentation, it says *"Search & Filter uses the main query to hook into and modify, so the templates by your theme for post type archives must also use this.  Any custom queries are not considered main queries by WordPress and should be removed from the template."* So, I think you have to use native WP functions to modify the main query so it within the realm of "normal use." I am not familiar enough with WP to suggest anymore than that I am afraid.

Comment: This may or may not help, but worth investigating: http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/  You will want to add `order by` into the query.

Comment: I have hard coded a solution by adding an invisible letter "a" and ordered them by alphabet, and it worked like a charm ! Thank you a lot for trying to help Rasclatt !